# How to split a string with dynamic integer delimiter inside this string in PHP?

Tags: php, string, explode

Hex string looks like:

```
$hexString = "0307wordone0Banotherword0Dsomeotherword";

$wordsCount= hexdec(substr($hexString , 0, 2));
```

First byte (`03`) is total number of words in string. Next byte is count for characters of the first word (`07`). And after 7 bytes there is another integer `0B` which tells that next word length is 11 (`0B`) characters, and so on...

What should function for exploding such string to array look like? We know how many iterations there should be from `$wordsCount`. I've tried different approaches but nothing seems to work.

Comment: It might be more efficient to use actual integers.  With this you have a word limit of 255 while you could support a word/char count of a 16bit integer.

Comment: @Flosculus - I have certainty that each word is shorter than 8bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be parsed with a simple `for` loop in *O(n)*. No need for some fancy (and slow) regex solutions.

```
$hexString = "0307wordone0Banotherword0Dsomeotherword";
$wordsCount = hexdec(substr($hexString, 0, 2));
$arr = [];
for ($i = 0, $pos = 2; $i < $wordsCount; $i++) {
    $length = hexdec(substr($hexString, $pos, 2));
    $arr[] = substr($hexString, $pos + 2, $length);
    $pos += 2 + $length;
}
var_dump($arr);
```

Comment: That is working. I've only had to change $lenght*2 since I didn't mentioned words are ASCII values in hex. Thank You Sir!

Answer (score 0):

you can solve this by iterating a pointer on the string with a for loop.

```
$hexString = "0307wordone0Banotherword0Dsomeotherword";

$wordsCount= hexdec(substr($hexString , 0, 2));
$pointer = 2;
for($i = 0; $i<$wordsCount;$i++)
{
    $charCount =hexdec(substr($hexString , $pointer, 2 ));
    $word = substr($hexString , $pointer + 2, $charCount);
    $pointer = $pointer + $charCount + 2;   
    $words[] = $word;
}

print_r($words);
```